# MySQL Connector/C++ wide char encoding

Tags: mysql-connector

In MySQL Connector/C++ both setString() and execute() functions take sql::SQLString string as input.

The class sql::SQLString doesn't seems to be wide-char compatible.

So how to pass wide char string to these function? Should I convert them to UTF8?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, passing UTF8 version of strings worked.